# Rails. How to remove quotation marks from query conditions when using a placeholder and string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create a search form (rails 3.1) where one of the search parameters allows the user to pick math symbols like <, >, = etc. I then want to use the value chosen as part of my query. The only problem is it puts quotation marks around it and results in invalid sql.

simplified example

```
params[:comparison] = '>'
params[:rank] = '3'

.where("rank ? ?", params[:comparison], params[:rank].to_i)
```

results in

```
PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "3"
LINE 1: ... WHERE (rank '>' 3)
```

I want to make it so its

```
WHERE (rank > 3)
```

**How can I create this active record query without the quotation marks around the greater than symbol in a way thats argument safe and not vulnerable to SQL injection exploits?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this very specific case, I would suggest you just check the value of `params[:comparison]` since you can easily "whitelist" it against the known safe values you are expecting which I assume are <, > and =

Example code:

```
known_comparisons = %w{< > =}
params_comparison = ">"

if known_comparisons.any? { |i| i === params_comparison }
  puts "were good"
else
  puts "bad value"
end
```

Then embed the value directly with string interpolation since you now are sure it is safe.

```
.where("rank #{params[:comparison]} ?", params[:rank].to_i)
```

Comment: If you wanted to be paranoid, you could have `ops = { '>' => '>', ... }; ops.default = 'unknown_operator'` and `.where("rank #{ops[params[:comparison]]} ?", params[:rank].to_i)`. That would give you an exception of some sort if an invalid operator was supplied and you'd get your whitelisting as well.

Comment: @mu Good catch on my interpolation/concatenation mixup, Thanks!

Comment: Good thinking and thanks for the quick response. That will do the job perfectly in this case. However, if there wasn't such a small number of known safe values is there an option or some kind of escape character or something that can be used with the placeholder to just remove the quotation marks?

Comment: @Daniel: I don't think so, placeholders are meant for values rather than operators, identifiers, etc. You'd just need to come up with some other whitelisting strategy. And don't forget this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

This problem reminds me Query class at Redmine. Source code at [here](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/repository/entry/branches/1.3-stable/app/models/query.rb).

```
class Query < ActiveRecord::Base

@@operators = { "="   => :label_equals,
                "!"   => :label_not_equals,
                "o"   => :label_open_issues,
                "c"   => :label_closed_issues,
                "!*"  => :label_none,
                "*"   => :label_all,
                ">="  => :label_greater_or_equal,
                "<="  => :label_less_or_equal,
                "<t+" => :label_in_less_than,
                ">t+" => :label_in_more_than,
                "t+"  => :label_in,
                "t"   => :label_today,
                "w"   => :label_this_week,
                ">t-" => :label_less_than_ago,
                "<t-" => :label_more_than_ago,
                "t-"  => :label_ago,
                "~"   => :label_contains,
                "!~"  => :label_not_contains }

cattr_reader :operators

@@operators_by_filter_type = { :list => [ "=", "!" ],
                               :list_status => [ "o", "=", "!", "c", "*" ],
                               :list_optional => [ "=", "!", "!*", "*" ],
                               :list_subprojects => [ "*", "!*", "=" ],
                               :date => [ "<t+", ">t+", "t+", "t", "w", ">t-", "<t-", "t-" ],
                               :date_past => [ ">t-", "<t-", "t-", "t", "w" ],
                               :string => [ "=", "~", "!", "!~" ],
                               :text => [  "~", "!~" ],
                               :integer => [ "=", ">=", "<=", "!*", "*" ] }


def statement
  # filters clauses
  filters_clauses = []
  filters.each_key do |field|
    next if field == "subproject_id"
    v = values_for(field).clone
    next unless v and !v.empty?
    operator = operator_for(field)

    # "me" value subsitution
    if %w(assigned_to_id author_id watcher_id).include?(field)
      v.push(User.current.logged? ? User.current.id.to_s : "0") if v.delete("me")
    end

    sql = ''
    if field =~ /^cf_(\d+)$/
      # custom field
      db_table = CustomValue.table_name
      db_field = 'value'
      is_custom_filter = true
      sql << "#{Issue.table_name}.id IN (SELECT #{Issue.table_name}.id FROM #{Issue.table_name} LEFT OUTER JOIN #{db_table} ON #{db_table}.customized_type='Issue' AND #{db_table}.customized_id=#{Issue.table_name}.id AND #{db_table}.custom_field_id=#{$1} WHERE "
      sql << sql_for_field(field, operator, v, db_table, db_field, true) + ')'
    elsif field == 'watcher_id'
      db_table = Watcher.table_name
      db_field = 'user_id'
      sql << "#{Issue.table_name}.id #{ operator == '=' ? 'IN' : 'NOT IN' } (SELECT #{db_table}.watchable_id FROM #{db_table} WHERE #{db_table}.watchable_type='Issue' AND "
      sql << sql_for_field(field, '=', v, db_table, db_field) + ')'
    elsif field == "member_of_group" # named field
      if operator == '*' # Any group
        groups = Group.all
        operator = '=' # Override the operator since we want to find by assigned_to
      elsif operator == "!*"
        groups = Group.all
        operator = '!' # Override the operator since we want to find by assigned_to
      else
        groups = Group.find_all_by_id(v)
      end
      groups ||= []

      members_of_groups = groups.inject([]) {|user_ids, group|
        if group && group.user_ids.present?
          user_ids << group.user_ids
        end
        user_ids.flatten.uniq.compact
      }.sort.collect(&:to_s)

      sql << '(' + sql_for_field("assigned_to_id", operator, members_of_groups, Issue.table_name, "assigned_to_id", false) + ')'

    elsif field == "assigned_to_role" # named field
      if operator == "*" # Any Role
        roles = Role.givable
        operator = '=' # Override the operator since we want to find by assigned_to
      elsif operator == "!*" # No role
        roles = Role.givable
        operator = '!' # Override the operator since we want to find by assigned_to
      else
        roles = Role.givable.find_all_by_id(v)
      end
      roles ||= []

      members_of_roles = roles.inject([]) {|user_ids, role|
        if role && role.members
          user_ids << role.members.collect(&:user_id)
        end
        user_ids.flatten.uniq.compact
      }.sort.collect(&:to_s)

      sql << '(' + sql_for_field("assigned_to_id", operator, members_of_roles, Issue.table_name, "assigned_to_id", false) + ')'
    else
      # regular field
      db_table = Issue.table_name
      db_field = field
      sql << '(' + sql_for_field(field, operator, v, db_table, db_field) + ')'
    end
    filters_clauses << sql

  end if filters and valid?

  filters_clauses << project_statement
  filters_clauses.reject!(&:blank?)

  filters_clauses.any? ? filters_clauses.join(' AND ') : nil
end

private

# Helper method to generate the WHERE sql for a +field+, +operator+ and a +value+
def sql_for_field(field, operator, value, db_table, db_field, is_custom_filter=false)
  sql = ''
  case operator
  when "="
    if value.any?
      sql = "#{db_table}.#{db_field} IN (" + value.collect{|val| "'#{connection.quote_string(val)}'"}.join(",") + ")"
    else
      # IN an empty set
      sql = "1=0"
    end
  when "!"
    if value.any?
      sql = "(#{db_table}.#{db_field} IS NULL OR #{db_table}.#{db_field} NOT IN (" + value.collect{|val| "'#{connection.quote_string(val)}'"}.join(",") + "))"
    else
      # NOT IN an empty set
      sql = "1=1"
    end
  when "!*"
    sql = "#{db_table}.#{db_field} IS NULL"
    sql << " OR #{db_table}.#{db_field} = ''" if is_custom_filter
  when "*"
    sql = "#{db_table}.#{db_field} IS NOT NULL"
    sql << " AND #{db_table}.#{db_field} <> ''" if is_custom_filter
  when ">="
    sql = "#{db_table}.#{db_field} >= #{value.first.to_i}"
  when "<="
    sql = "#{db_table}.#{db_field} <= #{value.first.to_i}"
  when "o"
    sql = "#{IssueStatus.table_name}.is_closed=#{connection.quoted_false}" if field == "status_id"
  when "c"
    sql = "#{IssueStatus.table_name}.is_closed=#{connection.quoted_true}" if field == "status_id"
  when ">t-"
    sql = date_range_clause(db_table, db_field, - value.first.to_i, 0)
  when "<t-"
    sql = date_range_clause(db_table, db_field, nil, - value.first.to_i)
  when "t-"
    sql = date_range_clause(db_table, db_field, - value.first.to_i, - value.first.to_i)
  when ">t+"
    sql = date_range_clause(db_table, db_field, value.first.to_i, nil)
  when "<t+"
    sql = date_range_clause(db_table, db_field, 0, value.first.to_i)
  when "t+"
    sql = date_range_clause(db_table, db_field, value.first.to_i, value.first.to_i)
  when "t"
    sql = date_range_clause(db_table, db_field, 0, 0)
  when "w"
    first_day_of_week = l(:general_first_day_of_week).to_i
    day_of_week = Date.today.cwday
    days_ago = (day_of_week >= first_day_of_week ? day_of_week - first_day_of_week : day_of_week + 7 - first_day_of_week)
    sql = date_range_clause(db_table, db_field, - days_ago, - days_ago + 6)
  when "~"
    sql = "LOWER(#{db_table}.#{db_field}) LIKE '%#{connection.quote_string(value.first.to_s.downcase)}%'"
  when "!~"
    sql = "LOWER(#{db_table}.#{db_field}) NOT LIKE '%#{connection.quote_string(value.first.to_s.downcase)}%'"
  end

  return sql
end

...

end
```